# RTSP stream from an ip camera onto a web page without using any server / webrtc / node or any other cloud based solutions

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, html5-video, rtsp, ip-camera

I've been trying to find solutions to get rtsp stream from my ip camera connected to a local network
All i find is really old solutions that are not supported anymore
is there any way to get streams without using any web rtc or any other third party solutions ?
any help or guidance will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you will need to use something to bridge protocols. Browsers don’t support RTSP.

[RTSPtoWebRTC](https://github.com/deepch/RTSPtoWebRTC)  is a easy to use modern solution. It requires a server though.

You could also convert the feed to HLS/DASH or just a streamable mp4/webm. Those can all just be done via ffmpeg/GSteamer.

Comment: What is the reason that browsers don't (want to) support one of the most asked streaming protocols ?

Comment: I personally haven't seen much demand for RTSP! It would add a lot of complexity/maintenance effort to browsers for little reward. RTSP also has some shortcomings compared to WebRTC. SRTP isn't mandatory, you can't start a RTSP session between two browsers (so you need a server). I don't have a full list, but that is off the top of my head.